# Changing database as a postgres statement

Tags: postgresql

I'm needing to grant public schema permissions to a role in postgres, in a .sql startup script. Normally it'd look something like:

```
\c dbname postgres
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO myrole
```

which works fine in the shell, however as a db datatement `\c dbname postgres` isn't valid (it gives a syntax error since it isn't sql/pgsql).

Comment: `\c` in psql means that you close the current session and start another one in a different database. You cannot work with multiple databases in a single connection (session).

Comment: You should be able to achieve the desired results using [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html). Take care to securely handle the access credentials for the dblink connection.

Comment: Connect to the right database right away, then you don't need to switch to a different one (in the same cluster) with `\c`. The rest works with SQL statements from within the same session.

Comment: Ideally I'm trying to have a single `provision_db.sql` file that will 1. create db, 2. create user, 3. grant user privileges on db, 4. grant user privileges on public schema on that db. 1-3 I can all do from SQL purely but the 4th one is stumped - do I really need to pop it out into a separate shell script to run a sql statement separately to achieve this?

Comment: Use `\c` in the script and execute it with `psql`.